# useState loading state not triggered

Tags: reactjs

I have a component which is accepting data and then setting it to XLSX. What i want to do is when i click download i want to set loading to true and show loading indication or something that user can know that is working. in my code download works but when i click on button loading is still false. why?

```
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Button } from "antd";
import { DownloadOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import * as FileSaver from "file-saver";
import * as XLSX from "xlsx";
import React, {useState} from "react";
import moment from "moment";

const ExportToXlxs = ({ data }) => {
  const [loading, setloading] = useState(false)
  const exportData = () => {
    setloading(true)
    const fileType =
      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8";
    const fileExtension = ".xlsx";
    let mappedData = [];
    data.map((item) => {
      return mappedData.push({
       //make map
      });
    });
    const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(mappedData);
    const wb = { Sheets: { data: ws }, SheetNames: ["data"] };
    const excelBuffer = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: "xlsx", type: "array" });
    const data = new Blob([excelBuffer], { type: fileType });

    FileSaver.saveAs(data, "file" + fileExtension);
    setloading(false)
  };

  return loading ? <div>loading</div> : (
    <Button
      type="primary"
      style={{
        marginLeft: "50px",
        alignSelf: "center",
      }}
      onClick={exportData}
      icon={<DownloadOutlined />}
    >
      Download
    </Button>
  );
};
export default ExportToXlxs;
```

Comment: It is an internal async call to update state hence when you setstate for loading it is true at the beginning and then It becomes false before the previous call is completed and the usestate sets loading as false if you can share sandbox I can post correct answer.

Comment: share a codesandbox link we will check

Answer (score 0):

You're running asynchronous operations in your `exportData` function. Try updating it to this:

```
const exportData = async () => {
    setloading(true)
    const fileType =
      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8";
    const fileExtension = ".xlsx";
    let mappedData = [];
    data.map((item) => {
      return mappedData.push({
       //make map
      });
    });
    const ws = await XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(mappedData);
    const wb = { Sheets: { data: ws }, SheetNames: ["data"] };
    const excelBuffer = await XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: "xlsx", type: "array" });
    const data = new Blob([excelBuffer], { type: fileType });

    await FileSaver.saveAs(data, "file" + fileExtension);
    setloading(false)
};
```

Now your operations will wait where needed before other operations like `setLoading` run asynchronously. Essentially what was happening was, you `setLoading` functions would run very quickly after eachother without first waiting for your `files to save. *See @vinayakshahdeo's comment on your question*

**Note:** There may be a chance some of the `await` keywords I added aren't necessary. I'm not too familiar with the libraries you're using.

Comment: Are you sure you added the `async` keyword in?

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like this make separate calls for the setstate

```
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Button } from "antd";
import { DownloadOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import * as FileSaver from "file-saver";
import * as XLSX from "xlsx";
import React, {useState} from "react";
import moment from "moment";

const ExportToXlxs = ({ data }) => {
  const [loading, setloading] = useState(false)
  const exportData = () => {
    const fileType =
      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8";
    const fileExtension = ".xlsx";
    let mappedData = [];
    data.map((item) => {
      return mappedData.push({
       //make map
      });
    });
    const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(mappedData);
    const wb = { Sheets: { data: ws }, SheetNames: ["data"] };
    const excelBuffer = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: "xlsx", type: "array" });
    const data = new Blob([excelBuffer], { type: fileType });

    FileSaver.saveAs(data, "file" + fileExtension);
    setloading(false)
  };

  return loading ? <div>loading</div> : (
    <Button
      type="primary"
      style={{
        marginLeft: "50px",
        alignSelf: "center",
      }}
      onClick={()=>{
      setloading(true);
      exportData();
      }
      icon={<DownloadOutlined />}
    >
      Download
    </Button>
  );
};
export default ExportToXlxs;
```

Comment: This doesn't prevent `setLoading` from immediately changing back to `false` in the `exportData` function.

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle I checked if his data is too small it will be processed really fast no matter what we do

Comment: none of those solution worked maybe you have codepen wit wokring?